# Отсортировать таблицу HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

При клике на ячейке с заголовком таблица сортируется. Например, при клике по ячейке «Фамилия» таблица сортируется по фамилиям в алфавитном порядке, при повторном клике на этой же ячейке, порядок переворачивается. Как это реализовать на Jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Таблица</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
    <div class="table-title">
        <h3>Участники:</h3>
    </div>
    <table id=Table">
      <tr>
        <th class="list_link number">Номер</th>
        <th class="list_link name">Имя</th>
        <th class="list_link lastName">Фамилия</th>
        <th class="list_link age">Возраст</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Никита</td>
        <td>Петров</td>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Артем</td>
        <td>Михайлов</td>
        <td>18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Евгений</td>
        <td>Троцкий</td>
        <td>21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Ушаков</td>
        <td>Кирилл</td>
        <td>17</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trArr = $('tr').not('tr:first-child')
// Сортировка по номеру

    if ($('.number').click(function(){

    {}

    // if ($('.name').click(function(){
    //  console.log('fff')
    // })) {}

    // if ($('.lastName').click(function(){
    //  console.log('fff')
    // })) {}

    // if ($('.age').click(function(){
    //  console.log('fff')
    // })) {}
})
```

Comment: Что бы могли вам помочь - приведите код, который у вас есть.

Comment: Есть плагин datatables.js, где этот функционал уже есть.

Comment: начните с того, чтобы разделить `thead` и `tbody`

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно зачем изобретать то что уже давно стабильно работает? Плагин "tablesorter" все это прекрасно делает, только надо правильно дать ему задание на исполнение.

Для поиска в сети используйте "Плагин jQuery для сортировки HTML-таблиц"